request being routed to wrong container ignoring PathPrefix(`/api/v1`)"
All requests to the portal.domain.com/api/v1 keep getting redirected despite setting PathPrefix(/api/v1) on the backend route rule. and the request endup being handled by the frontend container running nginx.
backend:
    build:
        context: ./context
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
        - srv_traefik-network # Use the same shared network
        - backend-network
    depends_on:
        - database
    labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true" # Enable Traefik for this service
        - "traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(\www.portal.domain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api/v1`)" # Route for main domain and path`
        - "traefik.http.routers.backend.priority=1" # Higher priority
        - "traefik.http.routers.backend.entrypoints=websecure" # Use HTTPS entry point
        - "traefik.http.routers.backend.tls.certresolver=myresolver" # Use Let's Encrypt for HTTPS
        - "traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port=4000" # The internal port to route traffic to

frontend:
    build:
        context: ./context
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
        - srv_traefik-network # Use the same shared network
    depends_on:
        - backend
    labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true" # Enable Traefik for this service
        - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(\www.portal.domain.com`)"# Route for main domain and path`
        - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=websecure" # Use HTTPS entry point
        - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls.certresolver=myresolver" # Use Let's Encrypt for HTTPS
        - "traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=80" # The internal port to route traffic to

i tried to put the backend service above to see if it was
precedence also set the  - "traefik.http.routers.backend.priority=1" to check if its a priority issue.
